# Where is the Outlook BCM Message Body in SQL Server DB?

Tags: sql-server, outlook, bcm

We are trying to get a dump of all our messages from Outlook Business Contact Manager (BCM).  The built-in export tool will give us contact information, but it will not give us the messages associated with each contact.

I have access to the SQL Server database that BCM is storing all of its information in.  Is there a field somewhere that has the body of all the messages in BCM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

18 hours and 50 cups of coffee later, I've finally found the field that contains the email message body.  It goes by the alias "ActivityNote", and can be found in the "ActivityFullView" view.  The reason its difficult to find is because the field data is obscured by the visual width of the column returned in your query results -- you only see the header of the email message, so it looks like:

```
"From: Contact Name<contact@emailaddress.com> To:..."
```

which is totally f*cking misleading to your eyes because it looks like an email header field instead of an email body field.

From there, you're just a few joins away from getting all of the contact information associated with that activity.

Hope this helps someone in the future.